# Fetch Hibernate associated entity list in pages

Tags: hibernate

I have hibernate entity say A which has a list of another entity say List list marked with oneToMany annotation. when I call getList() on a, it fetches all records from database, but I want to fetch it form of pages with fixed size, same as we can do with queries(`setFirstResult() and setFetchSize()`).
How can i achieve this for associated objects?

Comment: I have done a lot of research on this but couldnt find anything useful. Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not for now at least in my personal experience. In ORM's point of view, every persisted object represents some elements in database. I think this(use an object represents part of database elements) may confuse ORM with the list's persist status.

Comment: I agree with you, so this is not very useful in case number of child records is very big. consider 1000s of child records, nobody will want to have them in memory in one time.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know, there is no choice but to use query if you want to fetch associated entity in pages